# android change view based on spinner item selection

Tags: android, spinner

Hello i am new in android. It is possible to change view based on spinner item selection? Means if i select first item from spinner then first.xml is display. And if i select second item from spinner then second.xml is display. Please can anybody help me for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand you fully. Do you want to go to another activity when the spinner item is selected ??

Comment: No only display xml files based on item selection. Means using inflator inflate the xml files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a good guide: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/07/18/customizing-a-spinner-in-android/

Comment: The trick is to create your own ArrayAdapter (by extending) and override its methods.